# DropDownList / RadioButtonList - I don't need to validate selected value?

Tags: asp.net

I have used ASP.NET MVC and there when I have for example dropdown list - I must check if selected value is correct because user can change value on dropdown list using for example Firebug.

I am new in ASP.NET Web Forms. I have for example:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">One</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Two</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">One</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Two</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I have changed in Firebug selected value in DropDownList1 on 3 and in RadioButtonList1 on 3 and submit form. Then I have error:
*Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for va...*

**Does it mean that I don't need to validate selected value because user can't change it?**

Comment: What do you mean users can't change it? You just did. It basically only tells you to set `EnableEventValidation` to `false` only if you know what you're doing.

Comment: So I am safe and I don't need to check if selected value is on the list?

Comment: Reading @Tallmaris answer, I realize you asked whether you needed to do server-side validation. Check his answer ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, yes, `EnableEventValidation` works with that purpose in mind, you can read more here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In particular:

> When the EnableEventValidation property is set to true, ASP.NET validates that a control event originated from the user interface that was rendered by that control. A control registers its events during rendering and then validates the events during postback or callback handling. For example, if a list control includes options numbered 1, 2, or 3 when the page is rendered, and if a postback request is received specifying option number 4, ASP.NET raises an exception. All event-driven controls in ASP.NET use this feature by default.

So as a matter of fact you can be safe knowing that people cannot tweak your client HTML with the console and post back malicious data.

This said, you may want to put some guard in the server code just in case for some pages you need to disable event validation (it may happen if you want to submit strings that look like code or if you want to modify elements on the page with jQuery for example).

Comment: Wow thx - in ASP.NET MVC I don't have that interesting mechanism :)